# Creating an Excel Solver Macro that loops objective, variable cell, and constraint for multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

have some data that I would like to do a nonlinear regression on using solver. This is my first time using vba (or any kind of programming, actually). I have tried and tried with different combinations of codes from answers to questions here, but for the life of me can't get the macro to change any thing more than my first row.

My objective cell(K6), my variable cell (N6) and my constraint (N6>=0) all need to increment by one each time. {e.g.next values would be K7,N7, and N7>=0, respectively.} I have 356 rows of data.

This is the macro I've recorded, plus loop, solverfinish, and solverreset. I omitted anything that wasnt working. How can I get the three parts (objective cell, variable, constraint) to offset?

```
Sub solversolo()

For i = 0 To 356
'
' solversolo Macro
'

'
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$K$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$6", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$K$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=100000, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence _
        :=0.0001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
    SolverOptions PopulationSize:=400, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.075, Multistart _
        :=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
        IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
    SolverOk SetCell:="$K$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$K$6", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$6", Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve userfinish:=True
    solverfinish keepfinal:=1

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A question was asked so similar to this not that long ago - have you searched on here? If no - then you should...

Comment: yes I have, I've tried many things. I still get stuck at first row :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this construct - as an example :

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$K$6",
```

should be like this

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$K$" & i,
```

But you probably want to start the loop with 1 not 0...

Or you could do:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$K$" & 6 + i
```

Comment: If the answer is good, then accept it with the checkbox on the left, but best of luck with it.